# How to recover tabular data using a Neo4j query?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I've stored numeric tabular data as relationship properties in a Neo4j database. I would like to recover the data in tabular form.

For instance, one node was stored as follows:

```
MATCH (g:GNE),(p:EXP)
WHERE g.etr='5313' AND p.NExp='Bos_RM'
CREATE UNIQUE (p)-[r:Was_norm
    {Method:'NULL', time_t_35: '6.04',time_t9: '6.587',time_t14: '5.708',time_t31: '6.89',time_t224: '4.842'}
  ]->(g)
```

I tried a query like this:

```
MATCH (g:GNE)-[r1:Was_sel]-(e:EXP)-[r2:Was_norm]-(g)
WHERE e.NExp = 'Bos_SM'
RETURN g.etr,r2
```

but I'd like to recover the data in tabular form, and in the correct order.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly would you like the returned data to look? You can `RETURN g.etr, r2.Method, r2.time` etc., to break out the properties. And on what you like to order the data?

Comment: I'd like to recover the series of time but using a regular expression in word 'time'  `time_t_35 time_t9 time_t14 time_t31 time_t224` in column names and the number values in matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be possible to do what you want with your current data model, given Cypher's current capabilities. Part of the problem is that there is no way to get a property value without hardcoding (in your query) the name of the property. Another part of the problem is that property keys are not necessarily returned in the original order (or in any predictable order).

Instead, you can get around these problems by changing the way you store your tabular data.

For example, suppose you stored a node this way (notice that the collections are stored in the desired order):

```
MATCH (g:GNE),(p:EXP)
WHERE g.etr='5313' AND p.NExp='Bos_RM'
CREATE UNIQUE
  (p)-[r:Was_norm {
    Method:'NULL',
    times: [    9,    14,   31,  224],
    values:[6.587, 5.708, 6.89, 4.842]
  }]->(g)
```

Given the above data model, you can easily get the tabular data back as 2 separate arrays:

```
MATCH (g:GNE)-[r:Was_norm]->(p:EXP)
WHERE g.etr='5313' AND p.NExp='Bos_RM'
RETURN g.etr, r.times, r.values;
```

Or, if you wanted to get the data back in a single array:

```
MATCH (g:GNE)-[r:Was_norm]->(p:EXP)
WHERE g.etr='5313' AND p.NExp='Bos_RM'
RETURN g.etr,
  REDUCE(s =[], i IN RANGE(0,LENGTH(r.times)-1) | s + { time: r.times[i], value: r.values[i]}) AS table;
```

The result of the above query ([see this console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=vx2gr2)) would look like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| g.etr  | table                                                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "5313" | [{time=9, value=6.587},{time=14, value=5.708},{time=31, value=6.89},{time=224, value=4.842}] |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You can get properties as map (name-value pairs) if you return the nodes / rels directly

Comment: I did a blog post on how to turn cypher responses into CSV http://neo4j.com/blog/export-csv-from-neo4j-curl-cypher-jq/